# If statement checks regardless of the case of the letters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

I want to make my if statement flexible. If I input an exact info in my input box, my statement triggers but if the user put it in lower case or uppercase it cannot be detected. Here are the codes.

```
var find = _.findWhere($scope.allCast, {name: castName});
            if(!find){
                var cast = {
                    cpPortfolioItemId: id,
                    name: castName,
                    job: 'cast',
                    role: castRole
                };
                ContentAssessmentFactory.addCastDetail(cast);
            }else{
                $window.alert('Cast name is already exist.');
            }
```

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.filter()` with converting the `cast.name` and `castName` in Lower or Upper case.

```
//Return you an array of matched elements
var find = _.filter($scope.allCast, function(cast){
    //Convert both text in lower case and compare
    //If required you can use .trim() like castName.trim().toLowerCase() to strip whitespace 
    return cast.name.toLowerCase() == castName.toLowerCase();
});

if(find.length == 0){
    var cast = {
        cpPortfolioItemId: id,
        name: castName,
        job: 'cast',
        role: castRole
    };
    ContentAssessmentFactory.addCastDetail(cast);
}else{
    $window.alert('Cast name is already exist.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually works. But can I ask. What is the difference of _.find to _.findWhere? Can I do the same function on the _.findWhere?

Comment: @MixAustria, `_.findWhere` doesn't supports `predicate` as function thus used `_.filter`. And which library are you using `underscore` or `lodash`? if lodash the go through docs https://lodash.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making sure that string is in the same case, you'll want to strip the beginning and ending whitespace (if any) from the string to be tested.

User the trim() method for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to convert the text you're comparing (both the user input and your stored data) to either lower or uppercase during your comparison - that way it doesn't matter how someone tYpEs sOmEtHing.

http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/text/case-uppercase.html